# ReactOnRails pre-rendering error after deploying web app with new Ruby and Node versions with Capistrano

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, npm, capistrano, react-on-rails

**Background of the problem**

My [website](http://freelensia.com) is a Rails webapp running the [Sharetribe](https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe) open source code, with Puma & React on Rails to pre-render components. It has a TopBarApp component built by Sharetribe that displays top menus like Home, About, etc.

We recently upgraded the Ruby version from 2.6.2p47 to 2.6.5p114, and Node v7.8.0 to v10.15.3 (npm v6.4.1). After redeploying the new code with Capistrano, theTopbar no longer displays, and we can't access many subpages in our website. We get error msg:

```
Error during failsafe response: ERROR in SERVER PRERENDERING when prerendering TopbarApp with props
```

([Full Puma error log](https://pastebin.com/vQM3Lv2B) | [Full Puma access log](https://pastebin.com/2bYsbQfw))

This bug is generated when running the step `deploy:assets:precompile` with Capistrano deployment. I think have an issue when we build the code client for javascript (css files). Maybe it is not related to Ruby or Node version but something to do with memory when we build.

Checking Chrome developer console gives `TypeError: s is not a function`
[image]

**What I have tried**

I tried to remove `select nvm` when Capistrano deploy. My commit:
[image]

However, the error is still there because SSH must set npm and node versions.

Any ideas?